# How to run a Mac application From Java?

Tags: java, macos

I tried the code below to run a stand-alone utility app I created from Apple script but, I get a No File or Directory Exists error.

I put identical copies (for testing) in the project, dist, parent directories but, it didn't help.

So, my questions are:
Is my call to run the app bad (perhaps because it's not a Windows exe)?
How to run a mac app from java?

Thanks

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p=null;
    String s="MyLineInInput.app";
    try {
        p = r.exec(s);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AudioSwitcherView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Mac App Bunde is not an executable file, it's a folder with a special structure. It can be opened using the `open` command, passing the App Bundle path as an argument: `open MyLineInInput.app`.

EDIT:
Even better would be using `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("MyLineInInput.app"));`

Comment: Oh of course! Otherwise the real executable file is located in *.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: Perfect - It worked using the real executable (had to delete the space in the name).

Comment: Wow - the Desktop thing worked too and saves the hassle of getting the stub.

Comment: I get the error message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft\ Excel.app doesn't exist. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I used the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` method with the open command mentioned in the selected answer. I didn't use `Desktop.getDesktop().open()` since it unwantedly opened a terminal in my case and I didn't want to create an extra File object.

```java
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /System/Applications/Books.app");
```

#### Reason for adding '/System':

It seems we need to use the `/System` prefix for System apps. For user-installed apps, that's not required, and it can be like `/Applications/Appium.app`.

---

To answer @Pantelis Sopasakis' issue that I also faced initially -

> I get the error message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: >/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft\ Excel.app doesn't exist.

In this case, it could be simply due to not escaping the space characters in the path.

Environment: JDK 11 Zulu - macOS Monterey 12.2.1 - M1 Silicon