# Can't launch external App with java on OSX, why?

Tags: java, runtime-error

Im currently writing a simple application that executes external programs on my mac.

```
public class Example{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Process p;
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            p = r.exec("/Applications/Google\\Chrome.app");

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

}
```

This is the result:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/Google\Chrome.app": error=2, No such file or directory

Can someone explain to me why this Exception is thrown and a good solution?

I am on a mac!

Comment: @Kayaman You tell him good! Make him feel awful so he never wants to come back here! Way to go!

Comment: Can you launch the Chrome.app some other way, such as a double-click or whatever you do on a Mac? That will tell you if it's there and if you have permission to run it.

Comment: Well, the reason is pretty obvious, the problem is i cannot figure out why this is happening? This is the absolut path to the application that I am trying to execute.

Comment: This is not the way OSX Apps are launched.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361180/how-to-run-a-mac-application-from-java

Comment: @aGrusberg Aren't you missing a space between Google and Chrome?  "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app"

Comment: @Kayaman \ denotes the start of an escape sequence.  The use of both / and \ in the same path on a Unix-based system is totally fine.  (I also don't see what any of it has to do with the English language.)