# Permission denied when trying to run app through Java on Mac

Tags: java, macos

I try to write code to run an app through Java on Mac. Here is the code:

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  try {
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Numbers.app");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
```

but I get Permission denied error:

is there any solution for it?

Comment: Add more details like where your jdk installed, how did you installed it. Show the command you run

Comment: A "app" is actually a folder bundle.  You may find that using `Desktop` works better [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361180/how-to-run-a-mac-application-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by adding "open /" before the path

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Applications/Numbers.app");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```